# ngOptions: add tooltip to selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

using the following json collection:

```
 $scope.searchscope = [

{ id: 0, name: "Base", description: "Search only the specified base object. The value is equal to 0." },
{ id: 1, name: "OneLevel", description: "Search the child objects of the base object, but not the base object itself.The value is equal to 1" },
{ id: 2, name: "Subtree", description: "Search the base object and all child objects. The value is equal to 2" }
];
```

and the following markup

```
 <select data-ng-model="mySelections[0].SearchFilterMembershipsScope" data-ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in searchscope" data-ng-required="true"></select>
```

I have successfully generated a select with the 3 options. What would be the best angular way to display a tooltip of the currently selected items "description"? Also would it be possible to do this whilst the user is navigating the dropdown, i.e. making a choice, verses actually had made the choice?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a map from `id` → `description`. One way to populate it would be:

```
$scope.idToDescription = null;

$scope.$watch("searchscope", function(newval) {
    if( newval != null ) {
        $scope.idToDescription = {};
        var i;
        for( i=0; i < newval.length; i++ ) {
            $scope.idToDescription[newval[i].id] = newval[i].description;
        }
    }
});
```

And in your template use it as:

```
<select ... 
    title="{{ idToDescription[mySelections[0].SearchFilterMembershipsScope] }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, you might also consider looking at Tooltips in
[UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) and if you want fancier select boxes consider using [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) based on [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#events).