# How to create a tooltip for angular option using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use uib-popover to create a popup/tooltip for an option item generated by ng-options for a select box. I have tried two approaches but neither one is quite good enough. Ng-options works well because I have to have a default item selected, but I cannot figure out how to plug in uib-popover. If I use ng-repeat I feel like I have more control over how each option is generated, but I can't figure how to select a defualt item for that scenario. Here is the code I am using for the ng-repeat method:

```js
(function() {
 "use strict";

 var selectionTestViewModel = function() {

  var vm = this;

  vm.options = [
   { id: 1, val: "Option 1", desc: "Description of Option 1" },
   { id: 2, val: "Option 2", desc: "Description of Option 2" }
  ];

  vm.selectedOption = vm.options[0];

 };

 angular.module("angularApp").controller("selectionTestController", [selectionTestViewModel]);

}());
```

```html
<div class="page-content" ng-controller="selectionTestController as st">
 <h2>Selection Test</h2>
 <div>
  <select ng-model="st.selectedOption">
   <option ng-repeat="op in st.options track by op.id" value="{{op.id}}" title="{{op.desc}}">{{op.val}}</option>
  </select>
  <div>
   <span>Selected Value: {{st.selectedOption}}</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try like this   vm.selectedOption = vm.options[0].id;

Comment: I tried that, but that does not work. I would prefer to store the entire object in selectedOption so that variable can be bound to by other elements on the page.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679665/ngoptions-add-tooltip-to-selection